# Получение строки JSON по API Django в Android

Tags: android, django, json

Пытаюсь получить JSON строку по JSON с API. API самопальный(очень простенький) на Django. Если открывать в браузере /127.0.0.1:8000/get_last_data то все отображается.

Пытался запускать на эмуляторе (использовал /10.0.0.2:8000/get_last_data) получаю ошибку - Failed to connect to /10.0.0.2:8000.

Пытался запускать на реальном устройстве (/192.168.0.104:8000/get_last_data) получаю - Failed to connect to /192.168.0.104:8000. Пробовал использовать сторонний API (от VK) - работает.

Подскажите, как быть?

Comment: У тебя сервер на локалке одной машины а ты пытаешься получить данные с другой

Comment: @Oleksandr , на этой же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена путем использования ngrok

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).